# troubling with displaying in web browser of window phone 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

As usual, i open my project to work. But yesterday, i opened it and it doesn't work.
I even did not change my code. The day before it work and yesterday it did not.
Through my search on internet, I knew that's cause by changing Network. I don't know if it's right and i don't know how fix it.
my code is below, which loads site google.com to web browser of window phone 7.

```
   private void webBrowser1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri u = new Uri("http:///www.google.com", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        webBrowser1.Navigate(u);
    }
```

First times, i Lowed the security  in Tools>Options>Web browser>Security on VS2010 and then it's work. but the day after it did not work  again.
Please help me .
I can't do anything if this happen again.
Please help me. I really need a help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL(http:///www.google.com) seems to be wrong, Remove the extra '/' and try http://www.google.com